# Is it possible to model a pipe immersed in a fluid cavity using OpenModelica standard library?

Tags: fluid, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I would like to model a pipe immersed in a fluid cavity to study the heat transfer between the two fluids. I modeled this by using two `DynamicPipe` connected to the same `WallConstProp` but I'm not sure it is a correct way to model it. My question is : is there a specific component available in the MSL to model such a configuration or should I look in other libraries ?

Best regards,
Maxime

Comment: To clarify the namings: MSL means 'Modelica Standard Library' and is available in multiple tools, such as Dymola and OpenModelica (and more). The 'Modelica Standard Library' is open-source. There is no 'OpenModelica standard library' as far as I known.

Comment: So, the question should be about using 'Modelica standard library', not 'OpenModelica standard library'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such component for the heat transfer of a pipe to a surrounding fluid in the Modelica Standard Library as far as I know. If you only need heat transfer orthogonal to the flow in the wall then it is a good assumption to model both fluids with a pipe connected via a heat transfer. You can create your own heat transfer model based e.g. on a Nusselt correlation in order to model the heat transfer to a surrounding fluid for the second pipe.

The MSL offers basic components to provide a common basis for all Modelica users and works as a starting point. Specific applications can be covered by specific commercial or open source libraries.